# Rendering a different Javascript file in respond_to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am stuck in an (apparently) simple problem.
In my event_controller I have the i_like_it action:

```
  def i_like_it
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    ... # logic

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

In my case "i_like_it" is called with :method => PUT (it is an Ajax
call, "i_like_it.js.erb" will be returned as a script and it wil be
executed on the browser.)

**I would like render a Javascript file with a different name** (not
i_like_it.js.erb) , but I haven't found any option in the Rails API
docs.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render ??? }
end
```

Rails can render vanilla JavaScript with :js option, but **I don't want
use Javascript in the controller**.

Do you have any suggestion ?

Thank you,
Alessandro DS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `render :template => 'your_file_here'` instead of

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

Documentation for `render` describes a couple of other options too.

Answer (score 48):

If you do:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :action => "different_action" }
end
```

it will load RAILS_ROOT/app/views/*your-controller*/different_action.js.erb instead.

The format.js block just ensures that if it's a .js request, you have the proper headers set by default and it looks for .js.erb or .js instead of .html.erb by default.

You can also use render :file to render any arbitrary file on the file system that happens to have JS in it, or you could use any of render's other usual options. [There are a few of them](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000464).

Comment: In my case I have to render a js file of a different controller, then render :template => 'my_file' is more appropriate,
thank you,
Alessandro DS

Comment: And if I want to render a my_javascript.js.erb of another controller?

Comment: how do you call a file from a different folder, like a shared folder that isn't related to a controller? where does the relative path begin, and can you give an example of one (e.g. root/app/views/shared/vote.js.erb)?

Comment: `render action: "shared/vote"`. Although, since Rails3 you would just need to do `render "shared/vote"`. The :action key is so common they made it the default.